# What are paper humans called?

Tags: word-requests

In anime paper humans are shown frequently. When there is bad weather, people (in anime) do some angels (I think) from paper and post it on the window. What is it called?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the word [teru teru bōzu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teru_teru_b%C5%8Dzu).

From English Wikipedia:

> A teru teru bōzu (Japanese: てるてる坊主, lit. "shine shine monk") is a small traditional handmade doll made of white paper or cloth that Japanese farmers began **hanging outside of their window by a string**. In shape and construction they are essentially identical to ghost dolls, such as those made at Halloween. This talisman is supposed to have magical powers to **bring good weather and to stop or prevent a rainy day**. Teru is a Japanese verb which describes sunshine, and a bōzu is a Buddhist monk (compare the word bonze), or in modern slang, "bald-headed"; bōzu is also used as a term of endearment for addressing little boys.